# Enumeration of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ be a group with $e=g_1$ and $n$ is odd,

Set $$a_1=g_1$$
$$a_2=g_1g_2$$
$$a_3=g_1g_2g_3$$
$$a_n=g_1g_2...g_n$$

I am looking for example that all $a_i$ are different from each other i.e. $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. By the way it is  clear that $a_i\neq a_{i+1}$.

**Note** I had asked this question [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833474/can-all-of-them-be-different) but I think it is suitable for here. I require that $n$ is odd since there are many example when $n$ is even yet I found no example in the case $n$ is odd.

Comment: Why are you looking for an example of this?

Comment: I think for odd case, there is no group satisfying this condition but I am not sure and it is related the a cayley graph of the group.

Comment: In the commutative case $a_n=e=a_1$ for $n$ odd. So $G$ is not commutative.

Comment: So if one was to prove this cannot happen (with the group non-trivial), it suffices to show it when no initial sequence (except the one of length one) forms a subgroup. It is probably possible to do some further reductions like that.

Comment: Are there any groups you can confirm have, or don't have, such enumerations?

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant The OP writes s/he hasn't found any example when $n$ is odd. When $n$ is even, consider $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ where $g_1 = 0, g_2 = 1, g_3 = 2, g_4 = 3$. Then $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 3, a_4 = 2$.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A group $G$ with the property is called sequenceable. For a survey, see [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/DS10/pdf) by M. A. Ollis, which also tells that sequenceable groups are related to constructing row-complete latin squares. It is conjectured by Keedwell that $D_6,D_8$ and $Q_8$ are the only non-abelian non-sequenceable groups (see page 17); in particular, there should be none with odd order. It is known that an abelian group is sequenceable if and only if it has a unique element of order 2 (see page 5 for a proof). The article gives a list of groups that are known to be sequenceable. Apparently the question is not completely solved even in the case where $|G|$ has two prime factors.

However, some groups of odd order are known to be sequenceable, so an example to your question would be for instance the non-abelian group of order 21 (page 5; there are other examples as well).